# How to redirect output of PHP script DURING execution?

Tags: php, redirect

Is there a way to redirect output of an executing PHP script?

Of course this is trivial when launching the script via the command line. But how is this accomplished *after* the script is started?

**Note:** I need to capture the syntax errors and such *as well*.

Comment: redirect output where? to a file?

Comment: Possibly. Anywhere would be nice :)

Comment: See... I have a script that has data piped in and the output is discarded. I want to capture it somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to capture parser errors, you need to:

1. Make sure `display_errors` is `On`
2. Set an `error_prepend_string` and an `error_append_string`
3. Call `ob_start` from an auto_prepend file that runs before every PHP file you might be executing.
4. Use `set_error_handler` as you normally would, and make your callback sift through the named output buffer, looking for your custom error_prepend_string and error_append_string. If you find it, then shunt your output wherever you want it. If you don't, then let it go wherever it would normally.

Most of this can be achieved through `ini_set` calls, but the auto_prepend file will need to be specified in your php.ini.

Comment: Would it be possible to see a tiny example? :)

Comment: The only example I have is 422 lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's [output control](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) even in a command line script:

```
echo "123\n";
ob_start();
echo "456\n";
$s = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo "*$s";
```

Comment: Will this work for syntax errors? Will they get displayed? _[Better add that to the question...]_

Answer (score 1):

Syntax errors will output to STDERR, not STDOUT.  Make sure you also redirect STDERR in your pipline...

```
./myscript | myfile.php &> out.txt
```

Answer (score -2):

PHP has file i/o functions to write to a file.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

Comment: Like `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\test.php(5) : eval()'d code on line 10`

Comment: Those kind of errors. Maybe not _compiler_ errors technically.

Comment: @George - if your script can't be parsed, then there's no way it can redirect any output itself, since it can't run.  So I think you're out of luck.

Comment: Oh dear! Now my problem has been made worse - wait! What if the script does nothing more than call _another_ script with the code in it and _redirect its output_?!? Genius! I figured it out!